# What is the equivalent of this old SPI code using the current SPI library?

Tags: spi

I see some old library code that initializes SPI this way:

```
    SPI.begin();
    SPI.setClockDivider(2);
```

It does not use `beginTransaction`/`endTransaction` blocks, and `setClockDivider` is now deprecated. The current way to use SPI is to use transaction blocks where you pass the settings in.

What is the equivalent to this code using transaction blocks? Also, since the other settings (max speed, data order, data mode) aren't specified in the above code, there must be defaults. What are these defaults?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default is:

- Mode 0
- MSBFIRST

Not sure on the default speed. But:

`setClockDivider()` sets a speed relative to the system clock. So it's impossible to say what speed that will be since it'll be different on 8MHz boards compared to 16MHz.

`setClockDivider(2)` would be the same as using F_CPU/2 as a speed.

Answer (score 0):

I have example code [here](http://www.gammon.com.au/forum/?id=10892&reply=9#reply9).

The code is:

```C++
#if SPI_HAS_TRANSACTION
  SPI.usingInterrupt (0);  // I am using external interrupt 0
  SPI.usingInterrupt (1);  // I am also using external interrupt 1
  SPI.beginTransaction (SPISettings (2000000, MSBFIRST, SPI_MODE0));  // 2 MHz clock
#else
  SPI.setClockDivider(SPI_CLOCK_DIV8);
  SPI.setBitOrder(MSBFIRST);
  SPI.setDataMode(SPI_MODE0);
#endif // SPI_HAS_TRANSACTION

digitalWrite (SS, LOW);        // assert Slave Select
byte foo = SPI.transfer (42);  // do a transfer
digitalWrite (SS, HIGH);       // de-assert Slave Select

#if SPI_HAS_TRANSACTION
  SPI.endTransaction ();   // allow external interrupts to fire now
#endif // SPI_HAS_TRANSACTION
```

The default setting for SPI is to use the system clock speed divided by four.